# CsvReader.Read / CsvReader.ReadAsync duplicates data

Tags: c#, csv, stream, csvhelper, azure-durable-functions

Inside an Activity in Azure Durable Functions, I have a method that reads Csv file from certain index. Purpose of this method is to read 2000 rows of the file or until last row, starting from the specified index.

With files larger than 2000 rows, we reach BucketSize and stop while loop, so no duplicates occur.

However, with files shorter than bucket size, what should happen is that Read/ReadAsync method should return false when reached end of the file. What happens instead, is that upon reaching last row, reader starts working again from the specified index, and Read/ReadAsync method returns false only after full 2nd run. Which results in duplicated values.

```
public async Task<List<TModel>> StartProcessingBatchAsync(Stream stream, long index, CancellationToken token)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Processing CSV async");
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = CsvHasHeaderRecord });
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(_modelMap);

    stream.Position = 0;
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    stream.Position = index;
    var modelsList = new List<TModel>();
    var errorCount = 0;
    var rowCounter = 0;

    _logger.LogInformation($"Reading {_configuration.BucketSize} items starting from index: {stream.Position}");
    while(await csv.ReadAsync() && rowCounter < _configuration.BucketSize)
    {
        TModel record;

        try
        {
            record = csv.GetRecord<TModel>();

            Guard.NotNull(record, nameof(record));
        }
        catch
        {
            errorCount++;
            continue;
        }
        modelsList.Add(record);
        rowCounter++;
    }
    _logger.LogInformation($"Found {errorCount} errors out of {_configuration.BucketSize} items");

    return modelsList;
}
```

Any ideas why is that? Why Read/ReadAsync method is going for the 2nd run instead of throwing false at the end of the file?

Comment: "reader starts working again from the specified index". Are you talking about your own handling of the position in the stream when starting this. The index parameter you hand to this method we don't see how that is moved in outside code?

Comment: @Ralf I'm talking about the index parameter passed to the method. Let's say that this parameter is equal 1000 and points to the beginning of row number 10 for file that has 20 rows. What happens is that CsvReader.Read advances reader to the next record, from record 10 to 20 - each time I read what is inside the record, and in the next loop after reaching record number 20, .Read method should throw false as it reached the end of the file. What happens instead is that it again starts pointing at row 10.

Comment: What is `index`?  Is it the **line** in the CSV file to start reading from?

Comment: Can't follow completely but you may have trouble with buffering behavior of StreamReader and maybe the CsvHelper itself buffer things also. StreamReader first reads into a buffer before returning so if you change the Position in the Stream it isn't always of concern to the StreamReader as it might return things already in the buffer first. Might help to buffer the header information between calls to not need to change stream position afterwards.

Comment: @Ralf - that's very possible.  An even more basic problem is that `StreamReader` decodes binary to text using some encoding, frequently but not alwats UTF8.  Number of bytes / character will in general be variable and `StreamReader` doesn't report back the number of bytes consumed so far.

Comment: That's related to the other question how does he calculate index in the outside code(he still didn't show). The only thing he has there that might be close to correct is Stream.Position but only if buffering isn't in the way.

Comment: @Wolwgang - might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] with runnable  simplified code + CSV that we can use to debug your problem as indicated by [ask]?  As it is the code in your question does not compile due to missing definitions for `_modelMap`, `_configuration` and `CsvHasHeaderRecord`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/mp3b49.  We  would also need to see a simplified `TModel` and CSV file.  You don't need to share a CSV file with > 2000 rows, if you set the bucket size to something small, say 5 rows, you should be able to fit everything you need into your question.

Comment: Perhaps check that your `StreamReader` instance supports seeking with `CanSeek()`.

Comment: @Ralf Indeed it was about StreamReader buffering data. Once I implemented .Seek() on reader and added .DiscardBufferedData() after .Seek(), EndOfStream has been recognized as it should be, and CsvReader stopped multiplying data. Please feel free to add response to the question if you'd like so. And thanks for the help